# How cookies are saved in browser from PHP function

Tags: php, cookies, browser, server-side

```
setcookie("TestCookie", 123456);
```

As PHP being a server side language, it can't directly communicate with the browser.

Another similar but confusing thing for me: How do browsers translate header which are set from the PHP header function:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

I need theory/flow of the whole process instead of syntax.

Comment: [php.net: Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) and [RFC 6265 - HTTP State Management Mechanism](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6265.html) should cover most of it.

Comment: The cookies you set in PHP will be sent to the client in the response header. The `header('Location: ....')` will simply return a 302 status code with the redirect URL.